# How to generate a range of numbers between two alphanumeric values?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string, select, recursive-query

I have two Alphanumeric as input from the user, like for example WAC01001 and WAC01012.

How do I generate the numbers between these two values, using a SQL query, in separate rows? I want this

```
ID
---------
WAC01001
WAC01002
WAC01003
WAC01004
WAC01005
WAC01006
WAC01007
WAC01008
WAC01009
WAC01010
WAC01011
WAC01012
```

Similarly, for WAC01 AND WAC12, the expected result would be

```
ID
-----
WAC01
WAC02
WAC03
WAC04
WAC05
WAC06
WAC07
WAC08
WAC09
WAC10
WAC11
WAC12
```

The length of these input values is varied in size. some of these have leading zero after alphabet and some not.​

Comment: I think you may be suffering the [XY Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem) here.  As a lifetime software developer, I can't imagine this being a real need.  Do you just want to generate the list, or actually create rows with these values?  What language will be using to collect the input from the user?

Comment: Hi Dale, Those are the shorthand serial range numbers we except field service engineers to input, later through query we need to insert each serial numbers individually with other info.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not as easy as it may seem. The length of the string prefix could vary; and the number part may have leading zeros.

Here is an approach using a recursive query. The idea is to first separate the sring prefix from the numeric suffix (I assumed everything after the first digit in the string), then generate the series of numbers, and finally concatenate back into string (with respect the the length of the original string).

```
declare @str1 nvarchar(max) = 'WAC01001';
declare @str2 nvarchar(max) = 'WAC01012';

with cte as (
    select 
        n,
        cast(substring(@str1, n, len(@str1)) as int) num,
        cast(substring(@str2, n, len(@str2)) as int) end_num,
        left(@str1, n - 1) prefix
    from (select patindex('%[0-9]%', @str1) n) x
    union all
    select 
        n,
        num + 1,
        end_num,
        prefix
    from cte 
    where num < end_num
)
select concat(
    prefix, 
    replicate('0', len(@str1) - n - len(num) + 1),
    num
) res
from cte
order by num
```

If you need to handle more than 100 increments, then you need to add `option (maxrecursion 0)` at the end of the query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=579f612f4dbc998f63db0ea3d46b89db)**:

```
| res      |
| :------- |
| WAC01001 |
| WAC01002 |
| WAC01003 |
| WAC01004 |
| WAC01005 |
| WAC01006 |
| WAC01007 |
| WAC01008 |
| WAC01009 |
| WAC01010 |
| WAC01011 |
| WAC01012 |
```

Comment: Thank you​​​​ GMB, this is what I exactly wanted and tested a few scenarios and it is working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @v1 varchar(32) = 'WAC01001', 
        @v2 varchar(32) = 'WAC01012';

-- where does the string switch to a numeric sequence?
DECLARE @pos int = PATINDEX('%[0-9]%', @v1);

;WITH y AS
(
    SELECT 
      c = 2+LEN(@v1)-@pos,          -- where sequence starts
      prefix = LEFT(@v1, @pos-1),   -- fixed portion at beginning
      s = SUBSTRING(@v1, @pos, 32), -- start of numeric sequence
      e = SUBSTRING(@v2, @pos, 32)  -- end of numeric sequence
), nums AS
(
    -- recursive CTE to generate all the numbers in the sequence
    SELECT n = TRY_CONVERT(int, s), e FROM y
    UNION ALL SELECT n + 1, e FROM nums WHERE n < e
)
SELECT q.ID FROM nums CROSS APPLY 
(
  SELECT ID = prefix + RIGHT(REPLICATE('0', c) 
    + CONVERT(varchar(11), CONVERT(int, nums.n)), LEN(s))
  FROM y
) AS q
ORDER BY q.ID OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767);
```

If you can never have more than 100 values in the range, you can leave out the `OPTION (MAXRECURSION 32767)`. If you could have more than 32K values in the range, you'll have to change 32767 to 0, and the query will not be quick.

Comment: Thank you​​​​ Aaron​, this is working and I tested a few scenarios. Since I am not a SQL expert, I am not quite sure which one to use (Aaron V/s​​ GMB) with regard to performance aspect.

Comment: @Rajit Well, I suspect the performance won't be very different between the two solutions, since you're just generating a list of values. For something like this it can be quite subjective and you will probably want to choose whichever one is easier for you to understand, that you can envision maintaining and adapting to other problems, aligns more closely with code already in your system, that kind of thing.

Comment: Aaron, thank you very much. I really appreciate it.